# rpy2 (version 2.3.10) - importing data from R package into python

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

So I am trying to import some data from an R package into python in order to test some other python-rpy2 functions that I have written. In particular, I am using the `SpatialEpi` package in R and the `pennLC` dataset.

So I was able to import the rpy2 package and connect to the package correctly. However, I am not sure how to access the data in the package.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
spep = importr("SpatialEpi")
```

However, I can't seem to access the data object `pennLC` in the `SpatialEpi` package to test the function. The equivalent R command would be:

```
data(pennLC)
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, doing `data("foo")` can create an arbitrary number of objects in the workspace. In `rpy2` things are contained in an environment. This is making it cleaner.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
spep = importr("SpatialEpi")
pennLC_data = data(spep).fetch('pennLC')
```

`pennLC_data` is an `Environment` (think of it as a namespace).

To list what was fetched:

```
pennLC_data.keys()
```

To get the data object wanted:

```
pennLC_data['pennLC'] # guessing here, it might be a different name
```

Comment: Hey Laurent. This was very helpful. I am using rpy2 2.3.10 so some of the instructions you mentioned did not work correctly--there is no `data` method on a Package object now. But I put my answer below. Let me know if you have any suggestions on what I write below.

Comment: @krishnab Ah, yes. `data()` is in rpy2-2.4.0-dev. The use of `data=True`/`.__rdata__` is fine with rpy2-2.3.10. The function `data()` in 2.4 aims at making things a little less a hack.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out an answer based upon some guidance from Laurent's message above.

I am using rpy2 version 2.3.10, so that introduces some differences from Laurent's code above. Here is what I did.

```
import rpy2.objects as robj
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
spep = importr('SpatialEpi', data = True)
data = spep.__rdata__.fetch('pennLC')
```

First note that there is no `.data` method in rpy2 2.3.10--the name might have changed. But instead, the 2.3.10 documentation indicates that using the `data=True` argument in the `importr` will place an `PackageData` object under `.Package.__rdata__ . So I can do a`fetch`on the`**rdata**` object.

Then when I want to access the data, I can use the following code.

```
data['pennLC'][1]

In [43]: type(d['pennLC'][1])
Out[43]: rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame
```

To view the data:

```
print(data['pennLC'][1])
```